# Download multiple Url's from python Array

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

Attempting to retrieve urls from python array. I am attempting to use a for loop but am a little confused on next steps. The Urls have been parsed from an external site and are stored in the files variable.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

r = requests.get('https://earth-info.nga.mil/index.php?dir=coordsys&action=gars-20x20-dloads')
soup = bs(r.content, 'html.parser')
files = ['https://earth-info.nga.mil/' + i['href'] for i in soup.select('area')]

print(files)
```

Comment: `for file in files:
    print(file)`

Comment: I am attempting to use the request library, this line just prints out each url in the console no?

Comment: Yes. That is correct. What are you wanting to do? Are you wanting to iterate and retrieve the thml from those urls?

Comment: If you want to use the urls to retrieve the html from those, just do `for file in files:
    r = requests.get(file)`

Comment: I am attempting to download the urls that I was able to query within the files array. I want to automate this task as there are over 300 urls within that files array. Also where I could choose the path to where they should be located.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: So I am new to programming so excuse me if I say something incorrect. But I have a collection of urls -(that are zip files) that I was able to scrap using the request library and beautifulsoup. What I am attempting to do is iterate through said array and download the files to my local machine. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

r = requests.get('https://earth-info.nga.mil/index.php?dir=coordsys&action=gars-20x20-dloads')
soup = bs(r.content, 'html.parser')
files = ['https://earth-info.nga.mil/' + i['href'] for i in soup.select('area')]

for file in files:
    r = requests.get(file)
    
    # CODE HERE TO AUTOMATE WHATEVER YOU WANT TO DO
```